# Name for "Almost a vector space, but with $\mathbb{N}_0$ instead of a field"

Tags: vector-spaces, integer-programming

I have a finite set of vectors $V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$

Let us enumerate $V = \{\tilde{v}_1, \tilde{v}_2,...,\tilde{v}_m\}$

I have some space that I want to talk about (I spend a lot of time talking about and thinking about this space): $L\subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

$$L=\{k_1\tilde{v}_1 + k_2\tilde{v}_2+...+k_m\tilde{v}_m \mid \exists k_1,k_2,...,k_m \in \mathbb{N}_0\}$$

$L$ is *almost* vector space, with "basis" $V$ and the "field" of $\mathbb{N}_0$.
But not quiet, since $\mathbb{N}_0$ is not a field, or even a ring. Among other things it does not have an inverse element of addition.

Because I spend a lot of time thinking and talking about it, I want a name for it.
It seems like it should be the subject of some study,
given that should show up in lots of mixed integer programming problems.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}_0$ is not a field, so it's not just the additive inverses that are missing. It's not even a ring (which would be required for a module).

Comment: Good Point. Edited question

Comment: The closest thing is a [convex cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone). Possibly intersected with a [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group)).

Comment: So... all nonnegative integer-multiple combinations of your basis?

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist exectly. Only I'm not sure that the word basis can even be used, since that implies a vector space. Doesn't it?

Comment: @lhf Yeah that's what I thought too, an integer lattice with non-normalized unit vectors.

Comment: Depending on whether $\mathbf N_0$ includes 0 or not (I forget), this is either the monoid or the semigroup generated by $V$.

Comment: What is $\mathbb N_0$??

Comment: I would go with this and call it a module over the semiring $\mathbb{N}_0$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_%28mathematics%29#Generalizations

Comment: Is $\mathbb N_0$ a weird new name for $\mathbb N$? And if so, what are $\mathbb N_1$ and $\mathbb N_2$?

Comment: I'm not sure, the term "basis" makes sense. For that, you'd need to have linear independence, but without additive inverses either in $V$ or in $\mathbb{N}_0$, you essentially can't get a linear combination of any two vectors to add up to $0$, even if they're both the same. I might be wrong, though. Maybe there's another definition of linear independence that works.

Comment: @NikolasKuhn I agree that that is the best, but actually we should call it a semimodule over the semiring since the underlying additive semigroup  doesn't have inverses.

Comment: @bof $\mathbb{N}_0 = \mathbb{N} \cup \{ 0 \}$ and it's pretty common notation, at least in Germany...

Comment: @Fryie It is a basis of sorts, although not a vector space basis of course. When you use all he integers I've seen it called a "lattice basis" where the vectors generate a lattice of points.

Comment: @rschwieb ok, i didn't know, thanks for filing in.